# Creating lists within lists based on data

Tags: python

I have a list of data which uses a series of sub branches :

```
> {0;0}^Integer<42> {0;1}^String<The quick > {0;2}^Double<0.1>
> {1;0}^Bool<True> {1;0}^Point<{-99009.243235, 399042.762528,
> 15102.578893}> {1;1}^Arc<{-20951.867574, 430335.306547, 0};{-25310.087109, 429476.527113, 0};{-29697.790309,
> {1;2}^Line<{-39430.388946, 417565.387448, 0};{-34208.156216,
> 446281.842277, 0}> {2;0,0}^Plane<{0, 0, 0};{1,0,0};{0,1,0}> {2;0,1}^Vector<{1,0,0}> {2;1,0}^Integer<42> {2;1,1}^String<The quick >
> {2;1,2}^Double<0.1>
```

I will then break these up so I just look at their directory such as :

```
0;1
1;1
1;2
2;0,0
2;0,1
```

For example, 2,0,1, is showing there is three lists nested within each other, three deep.

I then want to be able to create sublists which then assign to these for example:

```
for index 0: [[]] (this holds a list within a list to match 0,1
```

then

```
for index 2: [ [ [][] ] ] (this holds a list within a list to match 0,1
```

What is the best way for me to do this on the fly when I am looping through all my data list, would I want to check if there is a list at the first index and if not make that list etc.

Once I have made the list, I then want to loop back over the string data and then place the data within the corresponding nested list.

Comment: I don't understand your question or the format of the "sub branches" in the data. Please [edit] your question and try to be more clear.

Comment: It seems that you're using some very specific file format. Can you show some simpler example: input and expected output. Also please show how you have tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A list can contain a variety of data types. A list like [4, 5, 6] has identical data types (only integers), while the list ['Facebook', 0.0, 'USD', 2974676, 3.5] has mixed data types:

Two strings ('Facebook', 'USD')
Two floats (0.0, 3.5)
One integer (2974676)

Comment: I don't think it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [1,2]
List1 = ['A', 'B'] 
List.append(List1) 
print("\nList after Addition of a List: ") 
print(List)
```